# Binding from Style to Control which applied the Style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, styles

I want to create the TextBox that has the Text-hint to describe TextBox value.
for this purpose I use VisualBrush that has TextBlock shows the TextBox hint when the TextBox is empty , then i coded the converter to convert HorizontalContentAlignment of TextBox(control that applied the style) To AlignmentX means that when objective TextBox e.g is left then the visualBrush shows left Alignment TextBlock but this pupose not came true. 
how I can fix this like bellow:

[image]

My XAML Code:

```
  <Window.Resources>
    <local:HorizontalAlignToAlignX x:Key="HAligToXAlig"/>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
        <Style.Resources>
            <VisualBrush x:Key="CueBannerBrush"
                         Stretch="None"
                         AlignmentX="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, Converter={StaticResource HAligToXAlig}}">
                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                    <TextBlock Text="search" Foreground="LightGray"/>
                </VisualBrush.Visual>
            </VisualBrush>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CueBannerBrush}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox"
             TextWrapping="Wrap"
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Width="342"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
</Grid>
```

My Converter Code:

```
    class HorizontalAlignToAlignX : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        AlignmentX Align = AlignmentX.Right;
        switch ((HorizontalAlignment)value)
        {
            case HorizontalAlignment.Left:
                Align = AlignmentX.Left;
                break;
            case HorizontalAlignment.Center:
                Align = AlignmentX.Center;
                break;
            case HorizontalAlignment.Right:
                Align = AlignmentX.Right;
                break;
            case HorizontalAlignment.Stretch:
                Align = AlignmentX.Center;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return Align;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged the converter part? at least to locate the problem..

Comment: @Kirenenko the Converter will not run according to BreakPoint

Answer (score 1):

**I fund my answer** by RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}} like bellow:

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <local:HorizontalAlignToAlignX x:Key="HAligToXAlig" />
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"
           xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
        <Style.Resources>
            <VisualBrush x:Key="CueBannerBrush"
                         Stretch="None"
                         AlignmentX="{Binding ConverterParameter=HorizontalContentAlignment, Converter={StaticResource HAligToXAlig}, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}}, Path=HorizontalContentAlignment}">
                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                    <TextBlock Text="search"
                               Foreground="LightGray"
                               TextAlignment="Right" />
                </VisualBrush.Visual>
            </VisualBrush>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Text"
                     Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="{StaticResource CueBannerBrush}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox"
             TextWrapping="Wrap"
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Width="342"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
</Grid>
```